# How to stop bats from spawning in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i'm trying to build a Five Nights at Freddy's 2 map on Minecraft but bats keep spawning I tried to kill them but there are to many to kill and I tried this command `/gamerule Domobspawning false` but that didn't work and `/kill @e[type=bat]` I have no idea how to get rid of bats

Comment: damn Zubats, they're everywhere! :P

Answer (score 4):

Gamerules are case-sensitive, and you can create your own gamerules. The correct gamerule is "doMobSpawning", while you've created a custom gamerule called "Domobspawning".

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

Savegame IDs are also case-sensitive. The correct ID is "Bat", not "bat".

```
/kill @e[type=Bat]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the bats to stop spawning try putting some source of light if you can in the area. To kill the bats I would just use splash potions.